# const in C vs const in C++

Tags: c++, c, constants

The given code compiles in C but fails in C++.

```
int main()
{
   const int x; /* uninitialized const compiles in C but fails in C++*/
}
```

What is the rationale and the reason behind the change from C to C++?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See the spec, in the compatibility appendix C.1.6:

> 7.1.6 [see also 3.5]
>
> **Change:** const objects must be initialized in C++ but can be left uninitialized in C
>
> **Rationale:** A const object cannot be assigned to so it must be initialized to hold a useful value.
>
> **Effect on original feature:** Deletion of semantically well-defined feature.
>
> **Difficulty of converting:** Semantic transformation.
>
> **How widely used:** Seldom.

Comment: A const object can be assigned to in C?

Comment: @Sergii I don't think so. And only file-scope definitions can be tentative in C. So there would be no way for a C program to provide a value for a `const` block-scope variable, I think.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb C (or C++) program can provide a value for a const variable using a cast: `const int i; *((int*)&`

Comment: @Yury It cannot. That is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 13):

Note that there is a legitimate use of an uninitialized, const-qualified object of automatic storage duration: its address can be taken and used as a unique key for labeling recursion levels in a recursive function. This is somewhat obscure, but worth noting. C makes this use efficient, while C++ requires you waste time and code size on initializing it. (In theory the compiler could perhaps determine that the value is never used and optimize out the initialization, but since you're passing around a pointer, that would be rather difficult to prove.)

Comment: You can also imagine a case where you use external magic (e.g. linker, or on the finished binary) to make sane content appear in such a variable, content that you don't want to (or perhaps can't) express as C source code.

Comment: If it has automatic storage, there's no way a linker could introduce it; there's one instance per function invocation, not anything global. And once there's UB (from accessing the uninitialized object's indeterminate value) at the source level, the compiler may have already generated random meaningless code before the linker even gets to see it.

Comment: That's true, I failed to see the "automatic".

Answer (score 6):

The `const` keyword was introduced to C in C89 in 1989, but had been with C++ since its creation in 1983.  So it was "backported" from C++ to C.

Initialization semantics are generally different in C and C++.  Although most of the time they "just do the thing you expect", there are cases where the differences become quite important.  C++ really isn't a superset of C after all.

For example, in C++ you can't:

```
goto x;
int i = 3;
x:
puts("Hello, world");
```

But that is perfectly legal in C.

Comment: Not going to downvote since it's interesting (and correct) but it doesn't quite answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

The ISO standard says (in 8.5 [dcl.init] [paragraph 9](http://www.kuzbass.ru:8086/docs/isocpp/decl.html)):

> If no initializer is specified for an object, and the object is of
>   (possibly cv-qualified) non-POD class type (or array thereof), the
>   object shall be default-initialized; if the object is of
>   const-qualified type, the underlying class type shall have a
>   user-declared default constructor.

if you try the same example after modifying to this:

```
int main()
{
   /*Unless explicitly declared extern, a const object does not have
 external linkage and must be initialized*/
   extern const int x; 
   return 0;
}
```

it will get compiled. So this self explains the need of enforcing this error to c++, declaring const vars without initializing and extern linkage is of no use, so coder must have added it by mistake.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
    int value;
    public:
        Test(int v = 0) {value = v;}
        int getvalue() const {return value;}
};

int main(){

    Test t(20);
    cout << t.getvalue();
    return 0;
     
    const double P1 = 68.68;
    cout<<P1<<endl;
    
    int star  = 57;
    int const *pstar = &star;
    cout<<*pstar<<endl;
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: How does this explain the difference between C and C++?