# What is the use of a const value in c if not initialised at declaration?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [const in C vs const in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087729/const-in-c-vs-const-in-c)

I have following code

**In C**

```
int main()
{
    const int k;//allowed but garbage and later we can't modify
    printf("%d",k);
}
```

> o/p=Garbage

**In C++**

```
int main()
{
    const int k; //not allowed from here itself
    printf("%d",k);
}
```

> o/p-compile time error

I having doubt what is the use of the `const` in C if it it is `allowed` to declare it with out `initialization` but after it `declaration` we can't `initialize` it.

But is `c++` it is good that we can't declare a `const` value without `initialization`.

Is there any use of the variable `k` in `C` or it is useless,if we only declare it as later modification is not possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has no use by itself.

However, there are compiler specific extensions where this becomes useful again. 
`C Compilers for embedded platforms`, for example, often have extensions that allow to give a variable a fixed address, or as an alias for an memory mapped I/O port.

The `const` would indicate / enforce that you `only read` from that address, for example a `memory mapped input port.`

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but you have to initialized that variable during declaration ,am I correct ?If so then it is useless if we are declaring a variable with const modifier.

Comment: @peterchen: do you happen to know, when compilers make such extensions available in C do they tend to also (a) not support C++, (b) support C++ but not offer the extension, (c) offer the extension in C++ too, but skip the "initialization" of the I/O port, (d) something else?

Comment: Got my +1, I was completely "off the road"

Comment: @pradipta: if the variable maps to reading an I/O port (such as a parallel port), you do not want to initialize it, as you would do an unexpected write.

Comment: @Steve Jossop: I don't have enough experience with that. Note however that such a C++ compiler could allow the "uninitialized const" for exactly this purpose.