# Why const variable need not to be initialized in C?

Tags: c, initialization, constants

`const` variables in C++ must be initialized means `uninitialized const variable` isn't possible & it is a compiler error. But why it is not same in C language also?
Consider following program that compiles fine C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    const int a;
}
```

What is the reason to allow `uninitialized const`? Wouldn't it be nice If C also follows same rule as C++ does? Is it due to performance concerns that local const variable needs to be initialized every time when a function is called & initialization takes time?

Comment: **Moderator note**: Please use comments for requesting clarification/discussing the question asked. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference probably stems, among other things, from a significantly more relaxed approach to initialization in C language *in general*, not only with regard to `const` objects. For example, this code is illegal in C++

```
goto over;
int a = 5;
over:;
```

because it jumps into scope of `a` bypassing its initialization. Meanwhile in C this code is perfectly legal, with variable `a` having indeterminate value at `over:`.

The same logic applies to your `const int a` declaration. C language simply believes that an uninitialized object is not a big deal, even in situations where it is no longer possible to set it to a determinate value later.

The primary reason for stricter initialization requirements in C++ is introduction of non-trivial initialization (constructors) into the language, i.e. initialization that cannot be meaningfully bypassed. Scalar objects and their initialization in C++ just tagged along as small part of a much broader concept.

> Wouldn't it be nice If C also follows same rule as C++ does?

I don't see it. C and C++ are substantially different languages. And they treat `const` quite differently as well.

Answer (score 5):

> Why const variable need not to be initialized in C?

History.

`const` was specified in C++ from its beginning and the use met that language's goals.  `const` was later specified in C with a related but different meaning to minimize exiting C code compatibility issues.

Since C began without `const`, its later inclusion is more like a `read-only` modifier than a `constant` one.  This allowed existing compilers to essential treat `const` as *nothing* for writing to a `const` is undefined behavior.  Newer compilers/code could take advantage that `const` provides.

```
const int a;
a = 5;  // problem in C as code attempts to write `a`

// Really should be `const char *fred`, but allowed for backwards compatibility.
char *fred = "sally";
```

C++ took a stronger approach and demands the initialization.

See also [const in C vs const in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6087729/2410359)

Answer (score 1):

Because C is absolutely confident in the programmer and does allow him to do a lot of things including stupid ones like: `int *x = NULL; x[4] = 12;` that will be compiled without error and even without warnings by many compilers.

More precisely, `const` is just a promise that a programmer does that the variable should not be modified, and that compiler could considere it as constant if it can help optimizations. But the compiler will never enforce any run time rules to forbid to change a const value :

```
const a = 1;
int *ix = (int *) &a;
*ix = 2;
printf("a=%d\n", a); /* UB : could print 1 or 2 */
```

will be compiled without a warning. But it will invoke undefined behaviour because you modified an object declared as `const`.

I believe that not initializing `const` variables is allowed simply because current C specification does not forbid it ! In former versions, initialization was always optional. Maybe future versions could force initialization for automatic variables.

Anyway a global or `static const` variable is in fact automatically initialized (per C language specification 6.7.9 10) : *If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
explicitly, then: ... if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero; ...*

So `static const a;` is perfectly valid as is `const a` if `a` is global and in those case `a=0`.

Comment: It's also possible that some build systems may define means via which things that will be constant once a program starts could be changed between compilation and execution (e.g. by a utility that reads the link map and patches the executable).  The C Standard provides no means via which such things could occur, but there's no reason for it to forbid a construct that might be made useful via such means.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is convention.

In C, virtually no kind of object is ever *required* to be initialized, and has never been *required* to be initialized.

`const` objects are just one more kind of object with one special characteristic, why make an exception for them?